# Cooperation method with db and CKAN of virtuoso

Tags: ckan, virtuoso

Will there be the method to link rdf which I added to virutuoso to ckan?
How can you link to "sqlalchemy.url" with CKAN server if you list it?

OS: RHEL 7
■Server for CKAN
CKAN Version: 2.4.1

development.ini
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
sqlalchemy.url = postgresql://ckan_default:pass@localhost/ckan_default
sqlalchemy.url = virtuoso://[id]:[pass]@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/○○
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

■Server for Virtuoso
Virtuoso Version: 07.20.3212

I upload an RDF file from "Interactive SQL" of "Virtuoso Conductor".
I can acquire a result when I input sparql sentence in C which is usable by "Linked Data" tab choice of "Virtuoso Conductor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, CKAN does not support direct access to Virtuoso.

There are 2 extensions at http://extensions.ckan.org which you can find by searching for 'sparql' which may help solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.I see the URL that I had.